# Using 'World Time Engine' Service from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, session, timezone, ip-address

I am working with ASP.NET MVC. I need local time depending on user IP address. For that I am using a 'World Time Engine' service. This service need the IP address as input and send response with a XML result including the time zone related information of that particular IP address.

I have to send a get request to the service with the IP address.

```
http://worldtimeengine.com/api/ip/<apikey>/<ipaddress>
```

I need to call this service from Global.asax file when SessionStart() will execute and then store the service response in session for future usage.

My problem is I can not call the service from SessionStart() method. How to call this URL from SessionStart() or from one of my controller? What will be the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a web client

```
var url = "http://worldtimeengine.com/api/ip/<apikey>/<ipaddress>";
var worldTime = "";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    worldTime  = client.DownloadString(url);
}
//add worldTime to session
```

Comment: Yes that works for me. I wanted to show you the snippet, but can not able to write it in comment.

Comment: if you think it's relevant, add it to your question.  if my answer solved the problem, accept as answer.  if it helped up vote it.  that's the way stackoverflow works.

Comment: you will soon. it's a good idea to read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq and you'll get more out of stackoverflow.

Comment: for instance if you accept answer to a previous question you will have enough reputation to vote.